# ELK Stack - Kibana showing only logs of one log file

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I parsed two access log files using logstash and in the command prompt it shows both the log files being parsed. When I checked the elasticsearch head in the "Any Request" tab, there also it shows all the parsed logs.

But when I try to view it on Kibana, it shows the logs of only the first file. How can I view the logs of the other file too?

This is my .conf

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["G:/logstash-1.5.0/bin/tmp/*_log"]
    start_position => "beginning"

  }
}

filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    mutate { replace => { type => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  } else if [path] =~ "error" {
    mutate { replace => { type => "apache_error" } }
  } else {
    mutate { replace => { type => "random_logs" } }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Maybe refresh you index pattern in kibana? Did you use the same index for both logfiles?

Comment: I haven't specified an index for the output in the .conf. Does it take the same index to all by default? Please refer the edited question with the .conf

Comment: The default index is "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}".  Assuming you're not using the date{} Index elsewhere in your config, all documents should show up in the same index (named for "today", UTC).  Do you see anything in the Elasticsearch log files?  It's possible for it to drop documents when it's unhappy.

Comment: It does show but only of the first file. For some reason the logs of the second file is not showing.